# Redirect .html files to .php equivalents and not show .php extension for any files

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I recently switched the file extensions on my site from .html to .php. As a result, I'd like to do the following:

1. Redirect .html files to their .php equivalents
2. Remove the .php extension from all urls
3. Extensionless urls should work (e.g., foo.com/bar should display the page located at foo.com/bar.php)

Here's my current approach, which I cobbled together from various sources:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

My approach has at least three problems:

1. When one tries to access foo.domain/bar.php, the .php extension remains (though, notably, foo.domain/bar *does* show the proper .php page)
2. While requests for .html files *do* display the proper .php page, the .html extension remains (I'd like no extension to display)
3. It's now impossible to access directories without including index.php in the url (e.g., foo.com/bar/ throws a 404 error)

As must be obvious, I find mod_rewrite really difficult. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Of the top of my head

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Options -MultiViews

# redirect /foo.html to /foo
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)\.html$ $1 [L,R=302]

# redirect /foo.php to /foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.php
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)\.php$ $1 [L,R=302]

# rewrite /foo to /foo.php if and only if /foo.php exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I gave your code a try, and here's what I discovered.

Rules #1 and #2 both work (both foo.com/bar.html and foo.com/bar.php redirect to foo.com/bar). However, #3 isn't working. Instead the server continues to look for the extensionless version of the file.

Also, my description was misleading in that I seemed to be saying that all the files are at the root. They're not. Thus, I believe that DOCUMENT_ROOT shouldn't be part of rule #3. Sorry for misleading you. (However, I did run tests with files at the root to see if DOCUMENT_ROOT is the problem. It's not.)

Comment: I must have been using PHP too much. `{$1}` should have been `$1`. I've edited the code above. Sorry about that. As you are in a subfolder you should use `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subfolder/{$1}.php -f`. Also make sure to also update `RewriteBase /subfolder`.

Comment: Thanks again for your help @Gerben. Sad to say, something remains amiss, as I still get a 404 error that indicates that the server is looking for an extensionless version of the .php file. Also, I should have been clearer about the location of the target .php files; they're not in any one specific directory but everywhere on the site. So I believe the rewrite condition for the third rules should be more generic.

Comment: Could you give some sample urls that are not working? Do urls that are not in a sub-subfolder work?

Comment: Since I've been working locally, I just uploaded the site to a staging server at http://staging.oblivio.com. For the time being, I'm applying the rewrites to the /pieces directory only, since that's where most of the files are. The following comment shows what I have in my htaccess file.

Comment: The only lines I changed from your most recent rules are line #2, which is now `RewriteBase /pieces` and line #14, which is now `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pieces/$1.php -f`

Comment: Sorry, it took me a few minutes to get the staging site working correctly. To do so, I needed to change rule #2 back to `RewriteBase /`. Also, to save you time, here are three urls to try: `staging.oblivio.com/pieces/puppet.php`, `staging.oblivio.com/pieces/grandmother.php`, `staging.oblivio.com/pieces/song.php`.

Comment: The second rule should have had a 302 too. See edit above. http://staging.oblivio.com/pieces/puppet seems to work, right?

Comment: I made the change, but the server is still looking for a nonexistent extensionless version of the file. Or at least that's how I interpret the fact that you get a 404 error when you try to access any of my sample urls above. (I just confirmed this by creating an extensionless version of puppet.php. Now when you try `staging.oblivio.com/pieces/puppet.php` you see the source for staging.oblivio.com/pieces/puppet.)

Comment: I appreciate you continuing to look at this. But sad to say, I get a 404 error for staging.oblivio.com/pieces/song as well as staging.oblivio.com/pieces/song.php. As an experiment, I just tried hiding rules #1 and #3, so that #2 is the only one in play. This too generates a 404 error, which I assume is not what should happen.